# Example in java for changing Kerberos password

Tags: java, authentication, kerberos

I have a web application where user can login over Active Directory. This is being implemented with Spring LDAP and CAS.

The problem is when the password expires - it cannot be changed over LDAP - I would need to use super user for it and this is not an option.

So... I am looking for code example which changes password over Kerberos and it must be executed on server side (not on windows host). It could use some lib - it does not have to be limited only to JDK.

Comment: If the password expires, they can't log into Windows anyway. Why no change it via Windows?

Comment: It's a web application, they can access it from home computer without being logged into windows domain.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out

This is the lib:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
    <artifactId>kerberos-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-M20</version>
</dependency>
```

And this is the code changing password:

```
KdcConfig config = KdcConfig.getDefaultConfig();
config.setHostName("my-kdc.server.fred.com");
config.setUseUdp(false);

KdcConnection conn = new KdcConnection(config);
conn.changePassword("user@DOMAIN.DE", "share123", "share322");
```